# Using && in case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a `case` statement with two separate conditions:

1. `controller_name` being `'pages'` or `'users'`
2. `controller_name` being `'static'` and `action_name` being `'homepage'`

This is what I've tried:

```
case controller_name
when 'pages', 'users'
  stylesheet_link_tag "style"
when 'static' && action_name == 'homepage'
  stylesheet_link_tag "homepage"
end
```

The first `when` works as expected, but the second `when` does not. I suspect that `&&` is causing the problem, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't work because `case controller_name` compares each `when`-value to `controller_name`, so you have something like:

```
('static' && action_name == 'homepage') === controller_name
```

which becomes:

```
true === controller_name
# or
false === controller_name
```

You could handle the `action_name` using an `if` statement instead:

```
case controller_name
when 'pages', 'users'
  stylesheet_link_tag "style"
when 'static'
  if action_name == 'homepage'
    stylesheet_link_tag "homepage"
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

or another `case`:

```
case controller_name
when 'pages', 'users'
  stylesheet_link_tag "style"
when 'static'
  case action_name
  when 'homepage'
    stylesheet_link_tag "homepage"
  when '...'
    # ...
  end
end
```

or maybe just:

```
case controller_name
when 'pages', 'users'
  stylesheet_link_tag "style"
when 'static'
  stylesheet_link_tag action_name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to to tackle this is to use a lambda as the matcher, this works because `#===` can be used to call a lambda.

```rb
static_home_page = ->(name) {name == 'static' && action_name == 'homepage'}

case controller_name
when 'pages', 'users'
  stylesheet_link_tag "style"
when static_home_page
  stylesheet_link_tag "homepage"
end
```